# Layout with many items autoresizing

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin, writing for iOS.
I'm trying to make keyboard view with numbers,
it will be 4x4.

How can I make that 4 buttons in line will be same width depending on screen width?

Edit: Seems like it can be done that way: make layout with hardcoded height, and width constraints calculate in runtime.

Comment: It is easy to achieve this in native iOS(not Xamarin.ios) , just let the 16 buttons (in .xib) margin =(0,0,0,0) ,and equal width and height. In Xamarin, you could create the button programmatically and adjust the width according the screen width in the method ViewWillAppear.

Comment: but if i want them to fill all with - only change width in runtime? 
In Android studio its weight attribute to achieve this

Comment: It's different in iOS, nothing like weight in iOS, You have to calculate the width by yourself or set the width constraint .we often use autolayout or  absoluteLayout(not recommended) to display the control.

Comment: thanks, got it now